# Trying to Iterate an array with Handlebars

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, mongodb, handlebars.js

Trying to figure out how to iterate on an array with Handlebars. I know I am missing something.

Node:

```
Docket.find({}, function(err, dockets){
    for(var i = 0; i<dockets.length; i++){ 
      var doclist = dockets[i];

           var model = {
              galleryName: doclist.galleryName,
              address: doclist.address
           };
    };
  res.render('dockets/index', model);
});
```

Handlebars:

```
    {{#each doclist}}
        <li><h3>{{this.galleryName}}</h3><br/><p>{{this.address}}</p></li>
    {{/each}}
```

Array in mongo:

```
[{
"Name":"Jeff",
"address":"Koehler st"
},
{
"Name":"Todd",
"address":"Mission st"
}]
```

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with your template, but the context with which you are rendering the template does not match what the template is expecting. You need a 'doclist' local containing an array of objects each having `galleryName` and `address` properties. The array you read from mongo should suffice. Try

```
Docket.find({}, function (err, dockets) {
  res.render('dockets/index', { doclist: dockets });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the JavaScript **[`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)** method to create a new object array with just the properties you want as follows:

```
Docket.find({}, function(err, dockets){
    var model = dockets.map(function (doc){
        return {
            "galleryName": doc.galleryName,
            "address": doc.address
        };
    });
    res.render('dockets/index', { "doclist": model });
});
```